# VC++: fprintf error in release mode

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm working in visual studio 2010 and I have code written in C.

If i run in 'Debug' mode, the code will run without any error or warning.

But if I run the same in 'Release' mode, errors and warning will appear.

Error List:

```
        warning C4013:'fprintf' undefined; assuming extern returning int
        error C2065: 'stdout': undeclared identifier
```

What is the reason? please help

Comment: Are you doing `#include <stdio.h>` in the source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an 'undeclared identifier' error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197030/what-is-an-undeclared-identifier-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> warning C4013:'fprintf' undefined; assuming extern returning int
> ```

It looks like you didn't include `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a difference in configuration between Release and Debug.
Check the values for "Whole Program Optimization", they may differ between the two build configurations.

---

I had the same problem in reverse: In Release mode everything was fine, but in Debug mode some functions like 'ext' (FFTW library) were reported as "undefined; assuming extern returning int".

The failing build configuration (Release in my case) had under project properties `Configuration Properties > General` the option "Whole Program Optimization" set to `No Whole Program Optimization`.

The successful build configuration had this set to `Use Link Time Code Generation`. When I set that option in my failing target as well, everything worked fine.